# showing the kernel density estimates of β̂ 1 OLS and β̂ 1 ROLS for your 1000 simulations

Tags: r, ggplot2, simulation, kernel-density, density-plot

I have the following problem: I did 1000 simultaions to get a vector of  ß^1_OLS and ß^1_ROLS, now I have to compare these two by plotting them both as a density function (I have to do it with ggplot()). Is it possible to plot a density from a vector?

Following my code, please excuse the mess:

```
>N=10000
X <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
E <- runif(N, min = -5, max = 5)

U = E * sqrt(X)

# population regression
Y <- 3 + 2 * X + U
population <- data.frame(X, Y)


# set sample size an repetition 
n <- 1000
reps<- 1000



# initialize the matrix of outcomes
fit_coef <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = reps)
fit_coef_ROLS<-matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = reps)


# #######loop sampling and estimation of the coefficients for OLS
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:reps){
  
  sample <- population[sample(1:N, n), ]
  fit_coef[i,] <- lm(Y ~ X, data = sample)$coefficients
  
}
fit_coef_ß1<- fit_coef[,-1] 
fit_coef_ß1
  
#######loop sampling and estimation of the robust coefficients ROLS
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:reps){
  
  sample <- population[sample(1:N, n), ]
  fit_coef_ROLS[i,] <- rlm(Y ~ X, data = sample)$coefficients
  
}
fit_coef_ß1_ROLS<- fit_coef_ROLS[,-1] 
fit_coef_ß1_ROLS
 

## Plot
df_coef_OLS<-as.data.frame(fit_coef)

plot_coef_OLS<-ggplot(df_coef_OLS, aes(x = fit_coef_ß1)) +
  geom_density()
plot_coef_OLS
```

I get a plot if I use this formular but i dont know how I can get the density of both estimators in 1 Plot, also the density is not in the range of [0,1]

I am thankfull for any support!
[This is the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyvVr.png)

Comment: Density doesn't need to be less than 1. It needs to be positive but it can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you just need to reshape your data to have the long format, i.e. the relevant coefficient of every iteration gets a row in a data.frame. You then need another column to declare from which simulation the row came from.

```r
library(ggplot2)

## Your code goes here (omitted for brevity)

df <- data.frame(
  coef = c(fit_coef[, -1], fit_coef_ROLS[, -1]),
  type = rep(c("OLS", "ROLS"), c(nrow(fit_coef), nrow(fit_coef_ROLS)))
)

ggplot(df, aes(coef, colour = type)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Is it normal, that the density is not between [0,1] or is there still a mistake?

Comment: It's common. Recall that the density integrates to 1, so what the density is depends on the range of the data. Here, the data is (roughly) between 1.95 and 2.05, so it should average around 10 to integrate to 1. Inversely, if the range was, for example, between 0 and 10, then the density should average to about 0.1.